# How to override the link color in WordPress header?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, hyperlink

so I have my menu at the top and I would like the link for "Contact Us" to be white.
I've assigned it a custom class and this is what I added so far:

```
.cta-button {
    border: 2px solid red;
    border-radius: 15px;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: red;
    top: -6px;
    color: #ffffff !important;
    transition: all .3s 0s;
}

.cta-button a:link, a:visited, a:active {
    padding: 0px !important;
    color: #ffffff !important;
    
}
```

Here it is live:
https://kkat.mavenpromedia.com/

As you can see I added the "important" but the link is still black and pulling from the link styles in the header module itself rather than my added code for that one link.

Thank you

Comment: Where/how are you adding this extra CSS?

Comment: In the "Theme Options" custom CSS page in Wordpress. ( using the DIVI theme )

Comment: Best bet is to look closely at the class that the button has using your browser dev tools for example, there are several classes and you would need to add them in with the cat-button class.

Comment: You need to make your CSS [more specific](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) than the existing CSS rules, however without seeing them in the question we cannot help. (Please note that questions here must be self-contained and not rely of external links that can break or change over time - therefore all the relevant code must be included directly in the question).

Comment: Do you want it like this? https://nimb.ws/cj14bR But why white when it will become invisible.

Comment: Hello m4n0, yes white but with red background ( sorry i changed it because i was sort of giving up ) thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding color like this -

```
.et_pb_menu_0_tb_header.et_pb_menu ul li.cta-button a {
   color: #fff !important;
}

.et_pb_menu_0_tb_header.et_pb_menu ul li.cta-button a:active,
.et_pb_menu_0_tb_header.et_pb_menu ul li.cta-button a:visited{
   color: #fff !important;
}
```

As I can see in the website the link color given already has !important written for it. Now when we have two !important css properties mentioned for same element, then we have to check for the specificity. You can learn about specificity in CSS here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Another note: Using too many !important to over-ride CSS property is a bad practice.

Comment: Hello! Thank you for taking the time to reply. When I add colour like that, it changes all the links to white rather than just the "contact link" which I have given a class too.

Comment: I have updated the code, by targetting the exact class name along with the specificity. Please check this now.

Comment: Glad to know that. Please upvote my answer and mark it as accepted answer if it helped you to solve the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 issues here:

1. the color of the link is not set at the `<li>` level (where you've added the class) but at the `<a>` level. You need to set the property `color` under the selector `.cta-button  > a`
2. The default color is already being set using `!important` (bad practice) so not only you must use `!important` as well but you also need to match the level of [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) . The best way to do that is to copy/paste the selector used in the template and add your custom class, like so

```css
.et_pb_menu_0_tb_header.et_pb_menu ul li.cta-button a {
    color: white !important;
}
```

of course you need to do the same for `:active`, `:visited`,…

Comment: Thank you, you and AKNair helped me a lot! It is working now. I understand about the !important already being set is bad practice, but due to it being done through a wordpress theme module automatically sets that, I'm not sure the best way to remove it. It looks like most things already have the !important added to it. I don't know, its confusing, but thank you very much!